# Syntax Error: expected name_wo_function_call

Tags: sql, plsql, syntax-error

I'm trying to write a script that will merge the contents of two tables (`table2`, `table3`) into a common one (`table1`).

I'm on a Oracle instance.

This is my code.

```
DECLARE
region VARCHAR2 :='REG1'; -- just for testing
BEGIN
  CASE
      WHEN region = 'REG1' THEN
          BEGIN
              MERGE INTO table1 USING (
                  SELECT 
                      field1 table2field1,
                      field2 table2field2
                  FROM table2
              ) ON (
                  field1 = table2field1
              )
              WHEN MATCHED THEN 
                  UPDATE SET
                      field2 = table2field2
              WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
                  INSERT (
                      field1,
                      field2
                  ) VALUES (
                      table2field1,
                      table2field2
                  );
              COMMIT;
          END;
      WHEN region = 'REG2' THEN
          BEGIN
              MERGE INTO table1 USING (
                  SELECT 
                      field1 table3field1,
                      field2 table3field2
                  FROM table3
              ) ON (
                  field1 = table3field1
              )
              WHEN MATCHED THEN 
                  UPDATE SET
                      field2 = table3field2
              WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
                  INSERT (
                      field1,
                      field2
                  ) VALUES (
                      table3field1,
                      table3field2
                  );
              COMMIT;
          END;
  END;
  EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
          NULL;
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
         RAISE;
END;
```

SQL Developer says:

```
Syntax error. Expected:
    name_wo_function_call
    name
    procedure_call
```

Now, I'm very new to plsql, I'm sure there must be something I'm missing.

How can I fix that error?

Comment: would help if you posted your actual code

Comment: @Sathya It is my actual code, I just changed table/field names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small changes:

in your `WHEN region ='REG2'` part, you have:

```
   SELECT field1 table3field1,
          field2 table3field2,  -- extra comma
    FROM table3
```

The extra comma just before from clause is incorrect.

likewise with

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
                  INSERT (
                      field1,
                      field2,  -- extra comma
                  ) VALUES (
                      table3field1,
                      table3field2,  -- extra comma
                  );
              COMMIT;
```

Though I suspect this is more of a copy+paste+botched anonymization error..

Also, CASE statements should end with `END CASE` so it should look like

```
DECLARE
  region  VARCHAR2 := 'REG1';                                                              -- just for testing
BEGIN
  CASE
    WHEN region = 'REG1' THEN
      BEGIN
        MERGE INTO table1
             USING (SELECT field1 table2field1, field2 table2field2 FROM table2)
                ON (field1 = table2field1)
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
          UPDATE SET field2 = table2field2
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
          INSERT     (field1, field2)
              VALUES (table2field1, table2field2);

        COMMIT;
      END;
    WHEN region = 'REG2' THEN
      BEGIN
        MERGE INTO table1
             USING (SELECT field1 table3field1, field2 table3field2 FROM table3)
                ON (field1 = table3field1)
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
          UPDATE SET field2 = table3field2
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
          INSERT     (field1, field2)
              VALUES (table3field1, table3field2);

        COMMIT;
      END;

      NULL;
  END CASE; -- end case, not just end
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    NULL;
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RAISE;
END;
```

Comment: That were typos, and I removed them as soon as I noticed them, they aren't in the question anymore. But the key was the `END CASE`. Adding it removes the syntax error. Thanks!